# python file iteration to change the formatting of output (going from a column to line)

Tags: python, list, for-loop, iteration

text file:

```
a
b
c
d
e
```

wanted output:

```
a,b,c,d,e
```

This is what I have so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import csv

list=[]
file= open('file.txt') 

for line in file:
    k=line.strip()
    list.append(k)
    print list
```

and the output is `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']`

Comment: It's not `python`, but `tr '\n' ','` would accomplish the job...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
print ','.join(open('file.txt').read().splitlines())
```

or, if it's going to be part of a larger code-base:

```
with open('file.txt') as fp:
    print ','.join(fp.read().splitlines())
```

(which will automatically close the file handle for you).

broken into bite-sized chunks:

```
with open('file.txt') as fp:
    text = fp.read()           # read the entire file content into `text`
lines = text.splitlines()      # split the text into a list of lines
output = ','.join(lines)       # use comma to join the lines into a string
print output                   # and print it.
```

Comment: Can you write out the entire script please, so I can understand it better and learn it for myself @thebjorn ?

Comment: that is the entire script.. run it and you'll see :-)

Comment: Just being picky here, but you could improve it a little bit by adding a `with` statement to open and close the file automatically